# Electrostatic force and deformation

Tags: electrostatics, material-science

Can an electrostatic force cause plastic deformation of an object ? So if we two charged opposite sheets of paper 
and we hold with our hands the two plates will the electrostatic attraction cause plastic deformation on the sheets?